# Are axioms in mathematics comparable to hypotheses in experimental sciences?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, axiom

Remark: my question deals more particularly with the axioms of set theory, arithmetic, probability theory, etc. I think the status of the axioms in geometry is clearer.

The French fictitious mathematician Bourbaki writes somewhere ( " The Architecture of Mathematics " in Jean-François Le Lionnais, Great Currents Of Mathematical Thought ) that the approach of the mathematician is comparable to the way experimental science proceeds.

The physicist makes observations and looks for the best explanation: he adopts as his theory the hypothesis ( or set of hypotheses) from which these observations can be deduced at minimuml cost.

If the comparison holds, the " observations" would, in mathematics, be some pieces of mathematical knowledge the mathematician wants to " secure" or justify , and the axioms would be the best available explanation. For example, the mathematician **first** wants addition to be commutative, multiplication to distribute over addition, etc., and **after that**, he seeks hypothesis or axiom(s) from which this **desired results** could follow.

My question is : is this view of axiomatizing in mathematics correct? and could this conception of axiomatizing helpfull to correct the feeling of gratuitousness or arbitrariness of axioms?

Comment: Not exactly. The disanalogy is that in mathematics, in the end, there is no underlying "phenomenon", with its own intrinsic structure, to observe. It is all built "by hand". Perhaps, a better analogy is to postulates in engineering design. However, it is simulated in higher level theories by the structures occuring in the lower level ones. For example, the axioms of homology theory were surmises from "observing" phenomena that occur in various techniques for deriving topological invariants (cell complexes, differential forms, homotopy, etc.).

Comment: Could you please add the precise original quote from Bourbaki. As far as I know Le Lionnais was not a member of the Bourbaki group. Thank you.

Comment: @ Jo Wehler  May I quote in French? My English is not good enough to give an accurate translation.

Comment: Bien sûr, if the original Bourbaki statement is in French :-)

Comment: Not even close. One is true by definition, the other a guess at best.

Comment: The purpose of positing axioms is to provide a formal foundation for whatever task is at hand. So, for instance, if we want to ground basic arithmetic, we go for the Peano axioms. If we want to do Euclidean geometry, we choose Euclidean axioms. If we want to work with proper classes, we use something like NGB. Etc. Usually, the idea is to strip the axioms as far down as possible but not so far that we can't do what we need to do...

Comment: ...That's why we go to such great lengths to prove results in poorer axiomatic systems that are already "known" in richer ones. The fact is, we really don't know whether ZF or other systems are consistent. We may believe them to be true, but that's not why we use them. Rather, we use them because we need to do math, and we don't currently have a better alternative.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost if you mean that science is a guess, or that it's axioms (such as they are) are a guess. On what do you base that?

Comment: @Richard I wrote that as a comment so I will not take the time to support what I wrote. On the other hand, if it were an answer I would definitely give you solid reasons for what I have said. Regards.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost you make a good point. Fair enough.

Comment: @Richard I am sorry for not answering your question earlier, but I have added an answer. Feel free to read it and ask for any further clarification, if needed. Regards.

Comment: A good recent debate is Penelope Maddy, [Defending the Axioms : On the Philosophical Foundations of Set Theory (Oxford University Press, 2011)](https://books.google.it/books?id=FtoUDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: See also Jaakko Hintikka, [What is the axiomatic method, *Synt* (2011)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41477650?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) and Dirk Schlimm, [Axioms in Mathematical Practice, *Phil.Mat* (2013)](https://philpapers.org/rec/SCHAIM-3).

Comment: See also : Joseph Kouneiher (editor), [Foundations of Mathematics and Physics : One Century After Hilbert New Perspectives (2018, Springer)](https://books.google.it/books?id=lZRdDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR4).

Comment: @Mauro Allegranza Thands for the references.

Comment: A piece designed for the mathematically inclined layperson, [How to Count Past Infinity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrU9YDoXE88) delves into the topic around the 13 minute mark.  In that video, he's grappling with infinity, and whether our axioms to handle infinity are "correct" in the way a scientific hypothesis can be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To state it short, no. The two are not comparable.

Now for the long winded version: the question is simultaneously relevant to two branches of philosophy: philosophy of science and philosophy of mathematics.

**A short primer on philosophy of mathematics:**

1. Mathematical realism is the view that mathematical entities actually exist and are "real" entities, either abstract (platonism), or concrete (mathematicism).
2. Anti-realism is the view that there are no mind-independent mathematical entities.

**A short primer on philosophy of science:**

1. Realism within science is the view that science provides us with the knowledge of THE world. That is, THE mind-independent externality.
2. Anti-realism is the view-point in which science does not, in fact, tell us anything about THE world, but it merely gives us the means to organize our sense-data.

Bearing that in mind, we can necessarily agree on one thing: Mathematical facts, or to be slightly technical, theorem, regardless of what philosophical school you belong to, are objective. That is, Mathematical statements, if proven true, are objective and unchanging. Its reason, however, of being objective are open to debate. Realists will argue it is true because  when we engage in mathematics, we engage in discovery of real abstract entities which do not change. Anti-realists, however, would argue the statements, if they are a nominalist, are true solely because that is how we have defined our system of mathematics.

**Where does a scientific hypothesis fall then?**

1. If you are Kuhnian (referring to thomas Kuhn), then for you a scientific hypothesis is really an axiom. That is, of course, only to the point you start experiencing unresolvable anomalies.
2. If you are a realist, then scientific hypothesis describe the world, but they are never certain (refer to problem of Induction by Hume)(Goodman's new problem of induction argues confirmation can never be formalized since it is necessarily semantic). Which, obviously implies, they are incomparable to axioms, because mathematical axioms are never uncertain; that is, they are never brought into question.
3. If you are an anti-realist, then scientific hypotheses are mere tools for you which can be discarded at any point in time (refer too instrumentalism). This, too, implies mathematical axioms and scientific hypotheses are incomparable.

**Summary**

Scientific hypotheses and mathematical axioms are vastly different. One is necessarily certain, while the other necessarily uncertain. They are comparable to one another only because we deduce further information from both. However, this similitude breaks in close scrutiny as well.

I hope that answered your question, feel free to ask for any clarification.

Comment: Axioms, in simplest terms, are statements which can be easily and widely accepted but can't be proven. They then stand as a starting point for any given hypothesis which should be held to some standard of proof.     Is it just me who finds your juxtaposition of 'real' and 'abstract' very humorous? CS

Comment: @user37981 Right.

Comment: @user37981 Not sure why you would find it humorous, any particular reason?

Comment: Sorry, it's just that Spinoza abhorred abstraction, so in the parlance I'm familiar with, real and abstract are oxymoronic. @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost

Comment: @user37981 No problem. Continental Philosophy is not my cup of tea.